# How to avoid duplicates between two tables on using join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, phppgadmin

I have two tables *work_table* and *progress_table*.

**work_table** has following columns:

```
id[primary key],
department,
dept_name,
dept_code,
created_time,
updated_time
```

**progress_table** has following columns:

```
id[primary key],
project_id,
progress,
progress_date
```

I need only the **last updated progress value** to be updated in the table now am getting duplicates.

Here is the tried code:

```
select
  row_number() over (order by a.dept_code asc) AS sno, 
  a.dept_name,
  b.project_id,
  p.physical_progress,
  DATE(b.updated_time) as updated_date,
  b.created_time
from 
  masters.dept_users as a,
  work_table as b
LEFT JOIN
  progress as p on b.id = p.project_id
order by
  a.dept_name asc
```

It shows the duplicate values for progress with the same id how to resolve it?[the progress values are integer whose values are feed to the form]

Comment: Do you need to use `SELECT DISTINCT`? You mention `UPDATE`, is this a sub query for an update query?

Comment: If you can add sample input records and ouput that would help. Based on the initial understanding, you can do  1,row_number() over (partition by id order by updated_time desc) and then 2, pick records where rownum=1(this step is missing in your query)

Answer (score 0):

Having reformatted your query, some things become clear...

1. You've mixed `,` and `JOIN` syntax ***(why!?)***
2. You start with the `masters.dept_users` table, but don't mention it in your description
3. You have no join predicate between `dept_users` and `work_table`
4. You calculate an `sno`, but have no `partition by` and never use it
5. Your query includes columns not mentioned in the table descriptions above

And to top it off, you use meaningless aliases like `a` and `b`?  Please for the love of other, and your future self (who will try to read this one day) make the aliases meaningful in Some way.

You possibly want something like...

```
WITH
  sorted_progress AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY project_id
          ORDER BY progress_date DESC -- This may need to be updated_time, your question is very unclear
    )
      AS seq_num
  FROM
    progress
)
SELECT
  <whatever>
FROM
  masters.dept_users   AS u
INNER JOIN
  work_table           AS w
    ON  w.user_id = u.id  -- This is a GUESS, but you need to do SOMETHING here
LEFT JOIN
  sorted_progress      AS p
    ON  p.project_id = w.id  -- Even this looks suspect, are you SURE that w.id is the project_id?
    AND p.seq_num    = 1
```

That at least shows how to get that latest progress record (`p.seq_num = 1`), but whether the other joins are correct is something you'll have to double *(and triple)* check for yourself.